# In R - Write an output csv file based on a condition

Tags: r

I am new to R.
I am writing a program where
(a) An input file (.csv) is being read – this file has 3 columns (all are numeric)
(b) Based on a condition of column 3 (say – where the value of column 3 is > 100), a new record is being added to an output file.
I am facing problem in writing the “if” clause.

When I write

```
 if (as.numeric(fld 3) > 100)
         {
         x <- data.frame(computed fld1, computed fld 2, computed fld3)
         write.table(x, "outputfile.csv", sep=",",append=TRUE,  quote=FALSE, 
 col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
    }
```

Then the following error message appears:

```
Error in if (as.numeric(fld3) > 99.99) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Next I tried with the following

```
cond <- as.numeric(x_compare) > 99.99
```

But I am unclear – how to trap the “TRUE” value of  ‘cond’ so that the new record can be written in the outputfile.

Any suggestions on how to construct this part of the program would be most welcome.

Comment: can you please dput() your dataset

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for `NA`s in your dataset.

`as.numeric(NA)` is `NA`. And `NA > 99` is also `NA`.

As per R docs:

> Usage
>   `if(cond) expr`
>
> `cond`
>   A length-one logical vector that is not NA. Conditions of length greater than 
>   one are currently accepted with a warning, but only the first element is used.
>   An error is signalled instead when the environment variable 
>   _R_CHECK_LENGTH_1_CONDITION_ is set to true. Other types are coerced to logical
>   if possible, ignoring any class.

So `cond` cannot be `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with dummy data-set:

```
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(v1=sample(1:100, 20, replace=T),
                 v2=sample(1:100, 20, replace=T),
                 v3=sample(80:150, 20, replace=T))

output <- split(df, df$v3>100)[[2]]
write.csv(output, "outputfile.csv")
```